# How to get an image of each letter from image with text

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, ocr

F.E. we have a scanned text document. For now, I have wrote a program which can get an image of a letter and recognize it. The thing which I don't understand now is how can I get from the whole scanned document the image representation of each text symbol? Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Seriously though no one is going to write your code for you, try something and come back if you have a specific problem. And provide a [MCVE] when you do.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder nice answer. Good luck.

Comment: I wonder what you need this for...

Comment: @KobyDouek for my graduate project.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I don't know how to do it. I Googled no information about someone's experience. So what should I show except my desire to know? Don't judge all people by yourself.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder If you know something - share it. If you just pretty smart and nothing - don't write here at all

Comment: @Ekaterina This site is a Q/A site not like a forum. Some topics are off topic or as in this case too broad. Some sites might let you ask someone to write the code for you. However, this site is not one of them.

Comment: @Ekaterina: such kind of comments are offensive and should be avoided. They never help. If you don't like the policy on this site (supporting people on narrowed down problems), you are also welcome to not write here.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I can't see where I ask to write code for me?

Comment: @Ekaterina Usually by hiring someone, I don't know any such sites just saying there might be some, this is not one of them.

Comment: @Ekaterina If you try something yourself and get stuck you are welcome to ask a question about specific code providing a [MCVE] when you do.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder lol. I ask you where in my message I asked someone to write a code?

Comment: @Ekaterina By not showing what you have tried and this line `how can I get from the whole scanned document the image representation of each text symbol?`. As you haven't shown you have tried anything you are essentially saying how can I do this or can you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a basic technique, use binarization and connected component analysis. This will give you "blobs" corresponding to the individual characters and you can get their bounding boxes.

You will face extra difficulties:

- some characters can touch and form a single blob. You will need some detection logics to split them, for instance based on size and/or bad recognition score. In the nasty cases (several touching characters, characters of uneven width), you will have to try different splitting hypothesis and keep the best.
- some characters are made of several blobs (such as accented letters), and some characters can appear fragmented. You can detect these situations when there are small blobs in a close vicinity. Here again, you will have to try grouping hypothesis (with a risk to group unrelated pieces) and keep the best.
- the blobs will be reported to you in random order and you will need some extra logics to reorder them in the reading sequence.

Comment: You know this question is off topic so why answer it? Good advice though, even though it is more advice than an answer.

Comment: I am here to help people. My first sentence *is* the answer: *blob detection*, nothing more to say. I have no plans to provide any code. The rest are extra goodies.

Comment: As are we all but by answering an off topic question you show others it is okay to answer such questions which leads to the downgrade of the site. My point is if you want to help people, help those who've tried something. If you want to help those that haven't tried anything yet become a lecturer.

Comment: That comment came off wrong, helping people who try is a lot more rewarding than doing the work for someone else.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: I prefer to give hints rather then kicking people out.

Comment: Then you can comment such hints or point them to a site where these types of discussions are welcome.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: thank you for the lessons.